# Preserve leading zeros in scrapy csv file

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, scrapy

I need to preserve the leading zeros while exporting zip codes to the csv file in scrapy. I have the following exporter to implement but it didn't help me.

```
import csv

from scrapy.exporters import CsvItemExporter


class QuoteAllDialect(csv.excel):
    quoting = csv.QUOTE_ALL


class QuoteAllCsvItemExporter(CsvItemExporter):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.update({'dialect': QuoteAllDialect})
        super(QuoteAllCsvItemExporter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

I extract zip codes in the following way. In this way they are never treated as integers:

```
addr = response.xpath('//address/span/text()').extract()

full_ad = ", ".join(addr)

zip_code = full_ad[-5:]
```

I need help in finding out the way to implement so that scrapy handles it automatically. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I need to preserve the leading zeros while exporting zip codes

It sounds like you are treating zip codes as integers. Don't do that; just treat them as strings. They have no integer meaning (you can't do any reasonable arithmetic on them), so don't interpret them as integers.

Then you won't have to worry about preserving any formatting.

Comment: even if i convert the zip codes to string, the behavior is still the same.

Comment: is there any other way to implement this?

Comment: *"convert the zip codes to string"* -- No, stop treating them as integers ever. Consume them as strings and leave them as strings always.

Comment: yes exactly, even if i never treat them as integers the behaviour is still the same. I extract the address from an xpath, convert the list to a string, then get the last 5 digits of the string as the last 5 digits is zip code. I have edited the question above to show how i have done this

Comment: Either you are converting them to integer somewhere, or it is your CSV reader who removes the leading zeroes. Are the zeroes there if you open the CSV file with a plain-text editor?